# Openstf installation and stf provider@service

Tags: android

I am trying to set up the open STF with the provider service, with Docker and was hoping if any one could walk me through it.

I followed through the guide and many of the suggestions here, but I could not get the proper solution.

Comment: What specific issues have you run into?  What guide are you referencing?  Do you have an error of some kind?  Consider reading [ask] and come back to [edit] in some additional detail so we can help you out.

Comment: OP is right.But I guess this is not the right place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

As you note, there is not currently a complete guide to starting up STF using the provided Dockerfile: https://github.com/DeviceFarmer/stf/blob/master/Dockerfile

I have written a more fully functional / complete example using docker-compose that can be found here: https://github.com/DeviceFarmer/stf_ios_support/tree/master/server

To start it up `docker-compose up`. You will need to also run a "provider" to provide a device to the server.

For providing an Android device you could use the stripped down STF code just for that purpose here: https://github.com/nanoscopic/stf-android-provider You can also use the main STF repo, but it is more difficult to build due to having many more dependencies. Note that Android device provision code is still dependent on Node 8. Higher versions of node won't work.

For providing an IOS device see https://github.com/DeviceFarmer/stf_ios_support

Setting up STF is non-trivial. Expect to have to do some measure of investigation, reading through source code, and trial and error.